# Matplotlib wont import, showing up as a type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I'm on an osx machine. Matplotlib was working fine a few days back, but today when i wanted to use it it just won't import. There are a bunch of lines and at the bottom it gives me a type error goes on about a copy function needing another variable. I've tried reinstalling it and still wont budge. any thoughts? I'm still fairly new to this so i have no idea whats going on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 5658, in <module>
    _reBracketExpr = Literal("[") + Optional("^").setResultsName("negate") + Group(OneOrMore(_charRange | _singleChar)).setResultsName("body") + "]"
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1480, in setResultsName
    return self._setResultsName(name, listAllMatches)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1483, in _setResultsName
    newself = self.copy()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1437, in copy
    cpy = copy.copy(self)
TypeError: copy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'E' and 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but when I migrated to OSX I had problems with matplotlib which were solved by changing the backend:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("MacOSX")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, it turns out matplotlib didn't like the directory I was in, which is odd. Just changing where i was trying to run it from worked.